# Proper way to use connection object from database in distributed java RMI application?

Tags: java, rmi

I am making an app that use RMI and DATABSE,but i wanted to follow a good resource utilization for my connection to the database. I wanted to have only one single instance to be created when the server start and I need other class needs to get the connection and do their  `executeQuery()`,`createStatement()` and return results to the client which be liter bind to `combobox`,`table`.

Comment: It is some how a connection pulling for all client threads connected to the server,every time they use the first connection to database.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to use a JDBC connection pool library such as boneCP. Do not attempt a do-it-yourself implementation of the connection pool: it is ridden with difficulties, and the ready-made alternatives always work due to the simple contract they implement.

I should also mention that using plain RMI is an obsoleted communication technique which was mainly associated with Java applets of the early 2000's. Today you would be much better served by a REST/JSON combination if you are doing something lightweight. Even on the enterprise level, REST/XML is gaining popularity, while for techniques based on Java Serialization it is waning. These newer technologies are preferred (among many other aspects) for the greater transparency of their line protocol, which helps diagnostics, debugging, and general predictability of the system as a whole.

Comment: J2EE is built on RMI. Your statement is extremely dubious.

Comment: EJBs are built with RMI. I haven't said anywhere that J2EE, or any part of it, is indispensable to all new Java projects. My book isn't relevant to this discussion, as it doesn't cover J2EE. I don't know why you're introducing all this irrelevant matter.

Comment: Marko, *what on earth are you talking about now?*

Comment: I was hoping you'd know that. A definition of "built on" that makes that statement true would be required to make your opening statement true. I am unaware of any such definition in the English language.

Comment: So you do admit that your opening statement is false. I wonder what motives you had to write a statement that you knew was false.

Comment: Marko, my motives are irrelevant, as are (1) 'indispensable', (2) my book, (3) human hair, (4) "J2EE is built in RMI", which is a statement of your own devising. Flagged as offensive.

Comment: "J2EE is built on RMI"---this is a statement of my own devising?